# Arranging bars in ggplot2 stem plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to arrange the bars in this stem plot from longest to shortest.  This https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/301-custom-lollipop-chart/ suggests that i can use the arrange function before I pipe into the graph.  I can't reproduce their example.  The bars end up in a sort of random order.  Any idea why the `arrange` is not working

```
 mtcars %>%
 mutate(mpg = as.numeric(mpg)) %>%
 mutate(x = factor(rownames( mtcars))) %>%
 arrange(mpg) %>%
 ggplot( aes(x=x, y=mpg)) +
    geom_segment( aes(x=x, xend=x, y=0, yend=mpg), color="skyblue", size=1) +
    geom_point( color="blue", size=4, alpha=0.6) +
    theme_light() +
    coord_flip()
```

Comment: in ggplot the x should be reordered like: `x=reorder(mtcars, mpg, min)`. No need to reorder the dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe  if you arrange by mpg before creating your x variable.

```
 mtcars %>%
 mutate(mpg = as.numeric(mpg)) %>%
 arrange(mpg) %>%
 mutate(x = factor(rownames( mtcars), levels = rownames( mtcars))) %>%
    ggplot( aes(x=x, y=mpg)) +
    geom_segment( aes(x=x, xend=x, y=0, yend=mpg), color="skyblue", size=1) +
    geom_point( color="blue", size=4, alpha=0.6) +
    theme_light() +
    coord_flip()
```

Comment: Sorry, I was away from my P.C. As bdempe says below, the factor x needs to be reordered. I've edited my answer above.

Answer (score 3):

I'm writing this answer quickly on my phone so forgive me for not having testable code, but you need to change the order of the factor rather rather arranging the data frame.